# Serving static content with custom Content-Type in Spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up my app to serve JSON Schema files. That part is easy, and done. What I'm struggling with is making it so that they serve with the correct Content-Type - `application/schema+json` - instead of the default - `application/json`.

My configuration is really simple:

```
override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/api/schemas/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/schemas/")
}
```

But I can't see anything obvious to change any headers except for the caching ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override **configureContentNegotiation** method. This is my code in Java. Bellow, I set *"text/javascript"* MIME type for javascript modules.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.mediaType("mjs", new MediaType("text","javascript"));
}
```